# Lazy Loading BrowserModule has already been loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, lazy-loading, angular2-modules

I am trying to implement lazy loading but getting error as following
**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already
> been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and
> NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

**

Need Help on this.
Here are my Modules

1. Shared MOdule

> ```
> @NgModule({
>
>   declarations: [TimePipe],
>   providers: [
>     EmsEmployeeService,
>     EmsDesignationService,
>     EmsOrganizationService,
>     EmsAuthService,
>     AmsEmployeeService,
>     AmsShiftService,
>     ValidatorService,
>     AmsLeaveService,
>     AmsAttendanceService,
>     AmsDeviceService,
>     AmsOrganizationService,
>     AmsAlertService,
>     AmsHolidayService,
>     AutoCompleteService,
>     AmsTimelogsService,
>     LocalStorageService
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     HttpModule,
>     ToastyModule.forRoot(),
>     AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
>       apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>     }),
>   ],
>   exports: [
>     FormsModule,
>     HttpModule,
>     BrowserAnimationsModule,
>     RouterModule,
>     MaterialModule,
>     MdDatepickerModule,
>     MdNativeDateModule,
>     ToastyModule,
>     FileUploadModule,
>     NgxPaginationModule,
>     NguiAutoCompleteModule,
>     AgmCoreModule,
>     TimePipe
>   ]
> })
> export class SharedModule { }
> ```

2.SettingModule

> ```
>  @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     CommonModule,
>     SharedModule,
>     SettingsRoutingModule
>   ],
>   declarations: [
>     SettingsComponent,
>     ShiftsComponent,
>     DevicesComponent,
>     AlertsComponent,
>     HolidaysComponent,
>     AlterTypesComponent,
>     AlterEditComponent,
>     ShiftTypeNewComponent,
>     DeviceLogsComponent,
>     ChannelTypesComponent,
>     ChannelTypeEditComponent
>   ], exports: [
>     SettingsComponent,
>     ShiftsComponent,
>     DevicesComponent,
>     AlertsComponent,
>     HolidaysComponent,
>     AlterTypesComponent,
>     AlterEditComponent,
>     ShiftTypeNewComponent,
>     DeviceLogsComponent,
>     ChannelTypesComponent,
>     ChannelTypeEditComponent,
>   ]
> })
> export class SettingsModule { }
> ```

```
3.SettingRoutingModule
```

> ```
> const settings_routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', redirectTo: 'shifts', pathMatch: 'full' },
>   { path: 'shifts', component: ShiftsComponent },
>   { path: 'shifts/new', component: ShiftTypeNewComponent },
>   { path: 'shifts/edit/:id', component: ShiftTypeNewComponent },
>   { path: 'devices', component: DevicesComponent },
>   { path: 'deviceLogs', component: DeviceLogsComponent },
>   { path: 'holidays', component: HolidaysComponent },
>   { path: 'alerts', component: AlertsComponent },
>   { path: 'alerts/types', component: AlterTypesComponent },
>   { path: 'alerts/:id', component: AlterEditComponent },
>   { path: 'channelTypes', component: ChannelTypesComponent },
>   { path: 'channelTypes/:id', component: ChannelTypeEditComponent }
> ];
>
>
> const routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', component: SettingsComponent, children: settings_routes }
> ];
>
>
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
>   exports: [RouterModule]
> })
> export class SettingsRoutingModule { }
> ```

4. App-routing-module

> ```
> const attdendance_routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', redirectTo: 'daily', pathMatch: 'full' },
>   { path: 'monthly', component: MonthlyComponent },
>   { path: 'daily', component: DailyComponent },
>
>   { path: 'daily/:empId', component: AttendanceDetailsComponent },
>   { path: 'details/:empId', component: AttendanceDetailsComponent },
>   { path: 'monthly/:empId', component: AttendanceDetailsComponent },
>   { path: 'leaves/:empId', component: AttendanceDetailsComponent },
>
>   { path: 'details/:empId/apply-leave', component: ApplyLeaveComponent },
>   { path: 'daily/:empId/apply-leave', component: ApplyLeaveComponent },
>   { path: 'daily/:empId/attendance-logs/:ofDate', component: AttendanceLogsComponent },
>   { path: 'monthly/:empId/apply-leave', component: ApplyLeaveComponent },
>   { path: 'leaves/:empId/apply-leave', component: ApplyLeaveComponent },
>   { path: 'leaves/new/apply', component: ApplyLeaveComponent },
>
>   { path: 'leaves', component: LeavesComponent },
>   { path: 'leave-balances', component: LeaveBalancesComponent },
>   { path: 'leave-balances/:empId', component: AttendanceDetailsComponent },
>   { path: 'manage-leaves', component: ManageLeavesComponent },
>
> ];
>
>
>
> const emp_routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
>   { path: 'list', component: EmployeeListComponent },
>   { path: 'list/:id', component: EmpEditComponent },
>   { path: 'designations', component: DesignationsComponent }
> ];
>
>
>
> const page_routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', redirectTo: 'attendances', pathMatch: 'full' },
>   { path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, children: emp_routes },
>   { path: 'attendances', component: AttendancesComponent, children: attdendance_routes },
>
>   { path: 'settings', loadChildren: './pages/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule' },
> ];
>
> // main routes
> const routes: Routes = [
>   { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
>   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
>   { path: 'pages', component: PagesComponent, canActivate: [UserGuard], children: page_routes },
>   { path: 'loginViaOrg', component: OrgLoginComponent },
>   { path: 'download', component: AppDownloadComponent },
>   { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
> ];
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
>   exports: [RouterModule]
> })
> export class AppRoutingModule { }
> ```

5.AppModule

> ```
> @NgModule({
>
>   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     PagesComponent,
>     LoginComponent,
>     EmployeesComponent,
>     OrgLoginComponent,
>     EmployeeListComponent,
>     EmpEditComponent,
>     DayEventDialogComponent,
>     AttendancesComponent,
>     MonthlyComponent,
>     AttendanceDetailsComponent,
>     DailyComponent,
>     DeviceDialogComponent,
>     LeaveActionDialogComponent,
>     LeavesComponent,
>     LeaveBalancesComponent,
>     ManageLeavesComponent,
>     ApplyLeaveComponent,
>     ConfirmDialogComponent,
>     ResetPasswordDialogComponent,
>     AppDownloadComponent,
>     DesignationsComponent,
>     AttendanceLogsComponent,
>   ],
>
>   entryComponents: [
>     DayEventDialogComponent,
>     DeviceDialogComponent,
>     LeaveActionDialogComponent,
>     ConfirmDialogComponent,
>     ResetPasswordDialogComponent
>   ],
>
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     // CommonModule,
>     SharedModule,
>     AppRoutingModule,
>     // feature modules
>     // SettingsModule
>   ],
>
>   providers: [
>     LoginGuard, UserGuard,
>   ],
>
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

Comment: Do you get this error on initial load of `index.html` or when you navigate to `/settings` ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer while navigating to  " /settings"

Comment: Are you sure **none** of all the involved modules (except `AppModule`) imports `BrowserModule`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I Have imported CommonModule in all modules (except AppModule)

Comment: Quite weird. Sounds like a bug to me. What Angular version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this version "@angular/animations": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.3",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153327/discussion-between-er-sushil-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I found Solution, I was importing BrowerAnimationModule in child.modules

Comment: Glad to hear you could make it work :) Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Import `BrowserModule,` `BrowserAnimationsModule`, `HttpModule` or `HttpClientModule` **only once**, preferably in your root module.

Comment: It works! Just a little add: if you're using both `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `BrowserModule`, they should be imported in the same module.

Comment: Also, for those who have NoopAnimationsModule, the same rule applies.  I had to also move that module.

Comment: THIS...So much this. I was trying to generate a lazy module with Angular CLI 9 and the output error was this non-descriptive 'cannot read properties of undefined' error. This answer saved me from burning my room down. I owe you Jota.

Comment: I had to import `AppRoutingModule` at the last, that resolved my error. But could not figure out the reason for that.

Comment: You sir saved my day. Have my upvote.
Would you be so kind to explain how this is necessary?

Comment: @Alvaro Your information and the answer of Jota should have made their way into the Angular-Docs! Thanks guys.

Comment: After this solved my issue, the next console error I got was "Cannot bind to ngIf etc etc" - which I figured was still a `BrowserModule`/`CommonModule` issue. I was importing both `BrowserModule` and `BrowserAnimationsModule`, and I got it to work by just removing `BrowserModule`. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: what if I want to lazy load BrowserAnimationsModule ( to reduce bundle size?)

Comment: How can we create a suggestion to Angular team, so they make this exception more descriptive, I've bee wasting almost one hour till I found this post, checking every place for an unnecessary BrowserModule

Comment: Yes, my case was all about BrowserAnimationsModule, I added it on every single remote module federation module I used material, and started to cause the issue. 1 day lost all due to an incorrect error description :(

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and **Jota.Toledo** gave the correct answer and I want only extend that: please check in shared module imports any modules that related with

> @angular/platform-browser/animations

and move those modules into app.module.ts

Comment: I had no NoopAnimationsModule imported in app.module.ts :). Solved my problem instantly.

Answer (score 11):

I also got the same error and finally, after little bit struggle, I was able to fix it.

Import these mentioned modules only once(in app-module only):

BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
LazyLoadImageModule (if using it),
CarouselModule (if using it),
InfiniteScrollModule (if using it),
HttpModule ( if using it)

Comment: This worked for me, but how am I supposed to use CarouselModule and others from other modules outside of AppModule now?

Comment: you put it in the module ts files in the "imports" section for the modules that should have access to it @BraelynB

Answer (score 10):

This error can occur if you have imported BrowseModule in some child.app module.ts also. Please make sure you import **CommonModule** in all modules other than app.module as it has browser modules.

Comment: you can import CommonModule from '@angular/common'

Comment: Still getting the same error. And you can check only in AppModule I have imported BrowseModule

Comment: yeah me too, only imported in app module

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had shared module which was importing BrowserAnimationModule. I was importing shared module in my root module. to solve this error remove all imports of BrowserAnimationModule from all modules and add it to root module.

```
imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to move **BrowserAnimationsModule** from any child components **imports**

Answer (score 1):

```
@First Import BrowerModule and in imports also first include BrowserModule import:[BrowerModule ] 

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If we declare `BrowserModule` in any module other than app `module(Duplicate)` this error will come. the In app module if we import 10 modules or plugins, first we have to import `BrowserModule` at the top and declare in decorates `(import:[BrowserModule ])` at the top

Comment: 1)If we declare BrowserModule in any module other than app module(Duplicate) this error will come.In app module if we import 10 modules or plugins,first we have to import BrowserModule  at top and declare in decorates (import:[BrowserModule ]) at top

Comment: I've edited your answer with that explanation. Please remember to edit your questions and answer instead of just commenting, when possible :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple modules, use `Browser` module only once in your app module or some custom module and use `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` in custom modules.

I was getting the same error , I was trying to reuse components, directives, pipes in multiple components/modules. Instead I imported all reusable components in a core module and imported the core module in multiple components/modules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that in no other part of the application, a call or import of BrowserModule is being made. There are libraries that use the BrowserModule and by doing so they ruin the BrowserModule.

Answer (score 1):

In same issue I was also stuck for 2 days, but finally I had resolve it! let me share my experience, I have created custom external library for the purpose of `common components`. I deployed it over `azure devOps artifacts`. When  I installed it my project it's working fine as expected. Now when I try to import the some module as `loadChildern` within `app-routing-module.ts`. I am getting the same error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

My Project configuration is Okay, what a tinny mistake I have done, that is I imported both `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` within my external library, So I just removed `BrowserModule` from that, It's working fine without any issue or error

**What I have learned**

`BrowserModule` is a root module, we have to import it once in whole project within `AppModule` & we can use `CommonModule` in other modules. We cannot use both module `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` together.

This is what I have learned from this experience, If I miss understood then please let me know the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing BreadcrumbsModule from the shared module.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

The lazy module that I added into my project contained `BrowserModule` too.

That's when I removed it from the module, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention: You must have **a** "BrowserModule" in **root** and must have a "CommonModule" for **each** child component

Answer (score 0):

IDE Auto import! With standalone components, became new issue to the world of development. If you're using standalone components, it means in your project just one module - it is AppModule. Some IDEs like Webstorm, while creating Pipe/Component/... simply declares it in the AppModule, then IDE adding created Pipe/Component/... as import to your standalone component. So as you understood AppModule automatically brings BrowserModule second time. Solution, just make your Pipe/Component/... as standalone, remove all imports/exports, remove AppModule from import section.

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular Documentation; note that this applies for `standalone` components.

https://angular.io/guide/animations#step-1-enabling-the-animations-module

On `app.config.ts` make sure to add `provideAnimations()` under providers

```
import {provideAnimations} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations()]
};
```