# use browser animations module in my library

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-lazyloading

I have to used browser animations module in my angular library because of my date picker and I am using lazy loading so I got several modules in my project when I want import my library in my modules
I get this common error "Lazy Loading BrowserModule has already been loaded".
is there any way to fix it?
thanks a lot

Comment: `BrowserAnimationsModule` should be imported by the application (not the library) in its root module. (see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations#step-1-enabling-the-animations-module))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy Loading BrowserModule has already been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975675/lazy-loading-browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

try to add :

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
            
  @NgModule({
      imports: [
         BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ ],
      bootstrap: [ ]
  })
```

in your appModule and remove the import of BrowserAnimationsModule from anywhere else.