# BrowserModule error only on lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular

I have a problem since my application was migrated to Angular 12.

My application launches without error. When opening certain pages, I get this error :

```
core.js:6498 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded.     
If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, 
import     CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as 
NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.js:1527:1)
at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as factory] (platform-browser.js:1549:58)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11457:1)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:11276:1)
at core.js:11314:1
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11314:1)
at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25345:1)
at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25399:1)
at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:3680:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:1)
at zone.js:1279:1
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28679:1)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:1)
```

I searched a lot on the internet, I checked that my application only loaded the `BrowserModule` once in `App.module.ts` (with `BrowserAnimationsModule`).

I noticed that the error pages are only those that use lazy loading. Routes declared without lazy loading are functional.

I figure the problem might be an external package that was already loading the `BrowserModule`.
But I can't get the ID.
My `package.json` :

```
"@angular/animations": "12.2.16",
"@angular/common": "12.2.16",
"@angular/compiler": "12.2.16",
"@angular/core": "12.2.16",
"@angular/forms": "12.2.16",
"@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.16",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.16",
"@angular/router": "12.2.16",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^7",
"angular2-ie9-shims": "0.0.2",
"angular2-notifications": "12.0.0",
"chart.js": "^2.7.2",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
"core-js": "2.5.4",
"exceljs": "1.10.0",
"file-saver": "1.3.8",
"flatpickr": "4.6.3",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"geojson": "0.5.0",
"innersvg-polyfill": "0.0.2",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"jspdf": "^1.5.3",
"jszip": "3.1.5",
"karma-scss-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
"leaflet": "1.3.4",
"leaflet-image": "^0.4.0",
"lodash": "4.17.11",
"moment": "2.29.1",
"moment-range": "^4.0.2",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
"ng-click-outside": "5.3.0",
"ng-recaptcha": "^8.0.1",
"ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
"ng2-file-upload": "1.4.0",
"ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "6.2.0",
"popper.js": "^1.15.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"rxjs-compat": "6.3.2",
"smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.4.3",
"swiper": "^4.5.0",
"tablesorter": "^2.31.1",
"tooltip.js": "^1.3.1",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

I also attempted to completely remove the `BrowserAnimationsModule` from `App.module.ts`. The error is still present.

I also did a search for `AppModule` in my project, it is only present in `main.ts` :

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I no longer know where to look.
do you see me giving me other avenues of research please?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

This module is lazy loaded and it triggers the error

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  AfpDatatableModule,
  AfpCommonModule,
  AfpSponsorDetectionRoutingModule,
  DatalistModule,
  AfpChartsModule
],
declarations: [
  SponsorDetectionComponent,
  SponsorDetectionFormComponent,
  MultiBarChartGenericComponent,
  SponsorDetectionTableComponent,
  SuspectedRoamingCoherenceComponent
]
})
export class AfpSponsorDetectionModule {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy Loading BrowserModule has already been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975675/lazy-loading-browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded)

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same error with just importing `BrowserModule` or `BrowserAnimationsModule` to child module. Please check lazyLoaded modules for `BrowserAnimationsModule`

Comment: Could you please provide a module that is throwing this error?

Comment: @Josef Katič
I have check all my project with a CTRL+F and the word Browser

Comment: I have edit my first post with a module in error

Comment: @ClaireSureau I'm curious if you were ever able to fix this error and if yes, what steps you took? we are in the same position and are really looking everywhere for a solution for that..

Comment: @hreimer I don't solve the problem.
I downgrade my version to return to Angular 11 for many weeks. When I have more time, I will try to find a solution again.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular documentation:

> BrowserModule’s providers are for the whole application so it should
> only be in the root module, not in feature modules. Feature modules
> only need the common directives in CommonModule; they don’t need to
> re-install app-wide providers.

[link](https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules#browsermodule-and-commonmodule)

You have an error - replace yours feature `BrowserModule` to `CommonModule`.

Comment: I had already read this documentation. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You must have `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `BrowserModule` in `AppModule`.

Comment: If I delete `BrowserAnimationsModule` and `BrowserModule` in `AppModule`, I still have the error. is there a tool to see which modules are loaded by which library?